# remove files that have mongoID as a name, which is older than a particular timestamp

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell

I have a following situation. People can upload images and then create some stories with these images. Not always they use the images for a story, therefore whenever they upload an image, I put that image in `tmp` directory (giving it a name of mongoID string: `507f191e810c19729de860ea.jpg`) and if they want to make a story with it, I do some manipulation with image and save it into a more appropriate directory.

So my `tmp` directory becomes crowded with unused images. Previously I was using a php script which was put on a cron job. This script iterated through all the images in a `tmp` directory, extracting timestamp from the mongoID string and if the timestamp is more than some amount of time old (let's make it 3 days) I was removing that image. This cron task was running every day at a specific time and I was pretty happy with it.

But after reading that I can [put a command on cron job](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-cron-job-using-sudo-command) a grief came to my heart. I was waking up every day and thought that my solution is not so good. So I was trying to use `find` command piped with `rm` command to achieve the same result, but (because you see my post here) with no luck.

Is there a way to do my task as a rm command?

P.S. [MongoID string is a 24 character string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) with letters `a-f,0-9`. So in my case I have images like

```
507f1f77bcf86cd799439011.jpg
507f1f77bcf86cd7a9439051.jpg
507f1f77bcf86cd799433fd1.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
find /tmp -mtime +5 -name "*.jpg" -type f
   -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}.jpg" -exec ls -l {} \;
```

- `-mtime +5` means files older than 5 days. Change it to your specific requirement.
- `-regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}.jpg"`
   comes from https://superuser.com/questions/411133/how-to-use-command-find-to-list-files-with-specific-filename-length.
- `-exec ls -l {} \;` shows info of the file. Once you are sure it works, change it for `rm {} \;`

Comment: The pattern will match longer filenames like 1111111111111507f1f77bcf86cd799439011.jpg as well. I'd add a slash after `.*`, like `".*/[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}.jpg"` to correct that.

Comment: @eminor that's very nice! I could not figure out how to match those leading `/` and you solved it. Thanks!